# How do I auto-fit a row height after merging cells?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, axlsx

I am generating a spreadsheet using:
Rails 3.2.12 with the axlsx gem (version 2.0.0)

There are cells which I want to have the text wrap and the height of the row adjust to match. This works when I use the following:

```
p = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = p.workbook

wb.styles do |s|
  wrap_text = s.add_style alignment: { wrap_text: true }
      wb.add_worksheet(name: "Sheet1") do |sheet|
        sheet.add_row [variable_containing_long_text], style: wrap_text
```

However, if I then merge that cell with others: Example
`sheet.merge_cells("A14:C14")`
the row height no longer auto-fits the contents.

How do I get the auto-height for the row based on contents after merging the cells?

Comment: How exactly are you generating this spreadsheet. Have you considered any alternatives?

Comment: Updated question with versions of rails and axlsx gem that I'm using. I originally started out using Excel XML format, but Excel never opened it without a warning so I switched to axlsx.

Comment: I am not a heavy user of this gem but have found open issues for this: https://github.com/randym/axlsx/issues/69 and here also https://github.com/randym/axlsx/issues/125

Comment: It appears to be an Excel issue.  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/autofit-row-height-doesnt-work/ca2a86b8-585a-46fd-a8a7-377e76ac5528?msgId=38709b42-daa4-4739-ae8c-ab8dcf2e2f0c